# Refactoring jQuery code 3 repetitive functions

Tags: jquery

First of I'm not sure if this is off-topic please remove if so. I have been messing around with some jQuery and have these 3 simple repetitive functions:

```
 $('#manualURL').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === 'Use Default URL') {
            $('#provUrl').prop('readonly', true);
            $('#provUrl').val(url);
            $(this).val('Enter Manual URL');
        } else {
            $('#provUrl').prop('readonly', false);
            $('#provUrl').val('');
            $(this).val('Use Default URL');
        }
    });
    $('#listManualURL').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === 'Use Default URL') {
            $('#listProvUrl').prop('readonly', true);
            $('#listProvUrl').val(url);
            $(this).val('Enter Manual URL');
        } else {
            $('#listProvUrl').prop('readonly', false);
            $('#listProvUrl').val('');
            $(this).val('Use Default URL');
        }
    });
    $('#registerManualURL').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === 'Use Default URL') {
            $('#registerProvUrl').prop('readonly', true);
            $('#registerProvUrl').val(url);
            $(this).val('Enter Manual URL');
        } else {
            $('#registerProvUrl').prop('readonly', false);
            $('#registerProvUrl').val('');
            $(this).val('Use Default URL');
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="list_url" type="text" id="registerProvUrl" value="https://provisioning.mymetis.co.uk/snom?mac={mac}" readonly placeholder="Provisioning URL"/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
           <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                 <input class="btn btn-default urls" type="button" name="registerManualURL" id="registerManualURL" value="Enter manual Provisioning URL"
       </div>
</div>
```

I got this far and then realised `.prev()` returns the element I'm clicking.

```
$('.urls').click(function () {
      $(this).prev('.form-group').find(':input').prop('readonly', false).val('');
});
```

The only difference is the ID of the button and the ID of the text field. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a chance to add same class to related button and textbox? Or Put ones ID to data attribute of another? If yes then that would be most reliable solution.

Comment: @billy.farroll, Never change HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the current value of your input and change it accordingly.

Here I used a ternary operator on the value of your input button :

*PS : I also edited the way you find your first input. You first have to find the closest `.form-group` then select its previous element.*

```js
$('.urls').click(function () {
      $(this).closest('.form-group').prev().find('input').prop('readonly', false).val('');
      $(this).val(this.value.includes('Default') ? 'Enter Manual URL' : 'Use Default URL');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="list_url" type="text" id="registerProvUrl" value="https://provisioning.mymetis.co.uk/snom?mac={mac}" readonly placeholder="Provisioning URL"/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
           <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                 <input class="btn btn-default urls" type="button" name="registerManualURL" id="registerManualURL" value="Enter manual URL">
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your current HTML, Use `.closest()` to traverse to ancestor `form-group` then  use `.prev()` to get its sibling.

```
var input = $(this).closest('.form-group').prev('.form-group').find(':input');
```

```js
$('.urls').click(function() {
  var input = $(this).closest('.form-group').prev('.form-group').find(':input');
  input.val('set text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" name="list_url" type="text" id="registerProvUrl" value="" readonly placeholder="Provisioning URL" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="btn btn-default urls" type="button" name="registerManualURL" id="registerManualURL" value="Enter manual Provisioning URL">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

However, I would recommend to group HTML fragment in a single container

```js
$('.urls').click(function() {
  var input = $(this).closest('.cointainer').find('.url:input');
  input.val('set text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cointainer">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control url" name="list_url" type="text" readonly placeholder="Provisioning URL" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="btn btn-default urls" type="button" name="registerManualURL" id="registerManualURL" value="Enter manual Provisioning URL">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```